# Can redirection of screen output to file change the result of a C++ code?

Tags: c++, io

I am having this very weird behaviour with a C++ code: It gives me different results when running with and without redirecting the screen output to a file (reproducible in cygwin and linux). I mean, if I get the *same* executable and run it like `./run` or run it like `./run >out.log`, I get different results!

I use std::cout to output to screen, all lines ending with endl; I use ifstream for the input file; I use ofstream for output, all lines ending with endl.

I am using g++ 4.

Any idea what is going on?

UPDATE: I have hard-coded the input data, so 'ifstream' is not used, and problem persists.

UPDATE 2: That's getting interesting. I have probed three variables that are computed initially, and that's what I get when using with and without redirecting the output to file

`redirected to file: 0 -0.02 0`

`direct to screen: 0 -0.02 1.04083e-17`

So there's a round-off difference in the code variables with and without redirecting the output!

Now, why redirecting would interefere with an internal computation of the code?

UPDATE 3: If I redirect to /dev/null, I get the sam behaviour as outputing direct to screen, instead of redirecting to file.

Comment: What kind of different results?

Comment: What are the different results?

Comment: What do you get for the './run >out.log' case?

Comment: What do you get if you try `./run | grep ".*"` or something with a pipe rather than to a file?

Comment: @Mark B: Sorry, I didn't get the purpose of pipe + grep. I tried the above command as is, and I get the same result as direct to screen.

Comment: I was trying to establish if it's sending the output to anything other than the standard display (for example a pipeline), or specifically to a file that causes the difference. If any redirection caused the problems that would have been another clue.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of effects of running with `nohup`, but the main one is stdin and stdout will be redirected to /dev/null.  In most cases, this means that stdout will be fully buffered instead of line buffered (its only line buffered if stdout is a terminal), so stuff that is output generally won't actually be output until you do an explicit flush.

**Edit**

Further updates make it unlikely the problem is directly related to the different behavior of nohup.  At this point, I would suggest running with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), as the most likely suspect is an uninitialized local variable or heap object.  Such a variable will have an unpredictable (but generally repeatable) value that depends on the environment in which the function was invoked -- mostly on what previously called functions have left on the stack, which might well depend on nohup as you're seeing

Comment: Doesn't it go to a log file by default?

Comment: no, it goes to /dev/null by default -- you need to explicitly redirect to a logfile, as the OP is doing

Comment: I have made some tests here and found out that it doesn't depend on nohup. It just depends on if I redirect the stdout to a file or to the screen. Would your comment apply as well?

Comment: @Biga - yes.  Differing launch environments (such as redirects or nohup) giving different results but the same environment repeatedly giving the same result is almost always an uninitialized variable dependency

Answer (score 0):

Do you use threads in this application?

I've seen subtly different behaviour in a poorly synchronized threaded application on Linux with/without nohup, although I don't know whether this would have been reproduced with cygwin.

In my case, I had two initialization threads, but the order in which they completed was (mistakenly) significant.  Without 'nohup' one would always complete first, but with 'nohup' the other generally would, I think the underlying cause was differences in IO buffering.

Comment: @Biga Oh well, it was worth mentioning.  I'll leave it here in case it helps somebody else.